# Signification of not parallel force and acceleration vectors, in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, forces, acceleration, vectors

the fact that acceleration and force vectors in special relativity are not parallel, is straight forward to derive. However, if we had to give a physical reasoning, argument behind this very mathematical observation, what it would be?